# este pequeño lio que tengo, ya he verificado en el directorio y se encuentra tal cual escrito la sintaxis de la ruta del directorio todo para resolver

Tags: python

imagen de ruta del dirrectorio[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El fichero está dentro de la carpeta "introduccion" y no aparece en la ruta que das. De todos modos, aclara mejor que problema tienes y añade algo más de contexto para que la pregunta pueda ser de utilidad para alguien más.

Comment: muchas gracias solucionado. se debe de tener en cuentra la ruta la cual se estable me hace falta la carpeta principal llamada intro entonces la linea 18 editada quedaria:  image=pygame.image.load('introduccion/images/cuadrado.png') # cargar imagenes